# Incompatible types when List of generic objects constructed outside of method call

Tags: java, generics, types

The following code will not compile

```java
import java.util.List;

class Scratch {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo<Object> foo = new Foo<>();
    Bar bar = new Bar();

    bar.bar(List.of(foo));  // Okay

    List<Foo<Object>> foos = List.of(foo);
    bar.bar(foos);  // Error
  }

  static class Foo<T> {}

  static class Bar {
    void bar(List<Foo<?>> foos) {}
  }
}
```

The line `bar.bar(foos);` casese this error:

> incompatible types: java.util.List<Scratch.Foo<java.lang.Object>> cannot be converted to java.util.List<Scratch.Foo<?>>

Why are the types incompatible when the `List<Foo<?>>` is constructed outside `bar()` method call?

Comment: Do you understand that `Foo<Object>` and `Foo<?>` are not the same?

Comment: Generics are not covariant, especially not the wildcard and `Object`. To understand why, try to add an item to the inner list in both cases.

Comment: You can change the parameter to `List<? extends Foo<?>>` if it's read-only.

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the `<?>`, because `Foo<?>` and `Foo<Object>` are not the same.

```java
void bar(List<Foo<Object>> foos) {}
```

Comment: That or fix the other end - depends what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You might also use a generic type in the method signature other than wildcard, that also still allows any Object type i.e below:

```
<T> void bar(List<Foo<T>> foos)
```

instead of

```
void bar(List<Foo<?>> foos)
```

Comment: Not much use in that unless OP wants to move around elements within the list.